# Searching through sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to search multiple sheets like this for certain words like `#work` and `#hobbies` and add up the numbers on the adjacent column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XRI6PtrTTIPK5wGj6cWaa9puWBjwdMimuxLnIp1sGFE/edit?usp=sharing

In this sheet, I need to add up the values in "Sheet 2" and "Sheet 3", for the cells in column B adjacent to the words `#work` and `#hobbies`. After I add them up, I want to put the total for `#work` and `#hobbies` in the cell adjacent to `#work` and `#hobbies` in "Sheet 1".

Essentially I want to assign `"Sheet 1!B1"="Sheet 2!B1"+"Sheet 3!B3"`

and

`"Sheet 1!B4"="Sheet 2!B4"+"Sheet 3!B9"`

Since I don’t know the location of these words, `#work` or `#hobbies` a priori, I need to search in column A, and find out the values and then add them up.

What code or function will help me evaluate this and do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` formula to perform this type of calculation.

### Formula

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A, A1, Sheet2!B:B) + SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A, A1, Sheet3!B:B)
```

### Screenshot

*Sheet2 & Sheet3*
[image]
[image]

*result*
[image]

### Explained

The first parameter of the `SUMIF` formula takes on the *criterion* range (column A in your example). The second parameter is the criterion itself. I needs to look for the entry in sheet 1 in column A: `A1`. The third parameter is the range to sum (if it differs from the criterion range), if the criterion is met.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. Hopefully, when I have more reputation points, I will be able to come and upvote the answer.

Comment: @alpha_989 I'm glad you returned and welcome on Web Applications !!